# Can new admins remove the creator of a page/group in Facebook?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups

I created a page in Facebook where I now have to add some fans of the page to keep my page continuing. Now after making others admin, I can also see the option to "remove admin". So my question is can the newly made admins remove me i.e. creator of the page? Does this happen in case of "group", too?

Comment: Is the page linked to your account? If so, no one can remove you.

Comment: @slybloty, I dont know what you mean by "page linked to your account". But yes I can post both as the individual and the page and I can exchange my account.

Comment: Have you created the page while logged in under your account?

Comment: @slybloty, Yes, I have done it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes any Admin can remove or create new Admins. This is why you should only add people you trust as co-admins.